# Why is android still using Java 8?

Tags: java, android

Just wondering why Android is very behind the latest versions of Java which the latest release is Java 11.

I understand we have Kotlin now which comes with some great features. But just wondering will Google ever update to the latest version if not, why?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Well for one, Java 11 isn't even the latest release of Java

Comment: Oracles new java licensing is probably the main reason why not to mention the lawsuit oracle has out on Google.

Comment: fyi, the latest version of Java SE is 13

Comment: This seems a good question, why down vote

Comment: Android releases almost never directly map to a given Java release. The most obvious reason is because Android does not use Java at all. It uses Dalvik, which brings with it its own Runtime (not a JVM), its own Bytecode format (Dalvik bytecode, not Java bytecode) and its own runtime library (borrowing a good chunk from Java SE and adding a lot of its own under `android.*`). Yes, a lot of it is written in the *Java language* and the runtime/bytecode are *similar* to Java bytecode, but different enough that directly picking up an OpenJDK to use in Android is far from practical.

Comment: Why closing? I mean why closing for opinion base? You could for lack of clarity or need more details because there is no code showing the problem, but this has an specific answer, Java 9 deletes code that it is used by Android, that is not an opinion that is a fact

Comment: @cutiko: very few people can give a fact-based answer to this question and those who can are almost certainly contractually obliged not to do so. Having worked on Android myself I can tell you that I can't chat about half of the things I'd like to talk about on this topic.

Comment: As an interesting sidenote: just a few days ago there was a commit which brings parts of `java.util` up to OpenJDK 9: [commit in question](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/72d94d47ac32bd55de714e40696f4cb253295f1b).

Comment: @JoachimSauer the question `Why is android still using Java 8?` can be answered, because in 9 there are missing methods, but the other questions can not as you explained. The *extra* questions seem like a common formatting problem to me.

Comment: @cutiko: that's not a good reason,  because they can easily patch that in when they move to OpenJDK 9 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 9 removed some methods used in the Android API

You can see the full list here

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-removed-features-3745614.html

To verify this, you can install Java 9 on your environment, use it and then run the tests using the command line; the test will fail indicating there is a problem with missing methods.

I can't remember which methods in specific, and please notice; that removed is not deprecated, it is deleted from the code.

My best **deduction** is:

- Kotlin is now a thing
- Oracle is suing Google

Refactoring the Android API to match the new Java versions gets low priority in that scenario